# Fetch specific gender in Codeigniter using mysql Database

Tags: codeigniter

Hello guys i am developing matrimony web application my problem is i have database field gender. if user is logged in then check the user gender if user is male then fetch all the female from database and if user is female then fetch all the male.
controller

```
   public function profile() {
    $this->load->view('header');

    $uname = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');

    if ($uname['gender'] == 'male') 
   {
        // $this->model_name->get_male();
        echo 'male';
    }
    //    $this->model_name->get_female();
    else 
    {
        echo 'female';
    }
}
```

updated code but it's fail condition every time . i have compare session user name to check user is male or female but it fail

**This is model**

```
class brid_groom_fetch extends CI_Model {
    function get_program_specific_gender() {
        $result = $this->db->get('bride_groom_register');
        return $result->result_array();
    }
```

Comment: What is your issue?

Answer (score 0):

First thing is you need to check the user currently logged in gender.

Example:

```
if($user['gender'] == 'male'){
  //run get male gender from database
  $this->model_name->get_male();
} esle {
  $this->model_name->get_female();
}
```

Model:

```
class brid_groom_fetch extends CI_Model {
    function get_male() {
        $result = $this->db->get('bride_groom_register');
                  $this->db->where('gender' = 'male');
        return $result->result_array();
    }
    function get_female() {
        $result = $this->db->get('bride_groom_register');
                  $this->db->where('gender' = 'female');
        return $result->result_array();
    }
}
```

Note: This is just an example to give you an idea. Hope this could help.

Comment: i have updated my controller but condition fail is correct to check user syntax to check user gender

Comment: @sms, Hey buddy glad it worked for you :) kindly accept my answer. Thanks!